# CorDapp JaCoCo Code Coverage

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jacoco, corda

I have a Corda based project with several CorDapp sub projects. I've been looking to add JaCoCo code coverage to this project. I'm looking to have a single code coverage report draw in an aggregate report of all the subproject JaCoCo reports.

To add JaCoCo to a maven project with several maven sub projects, I followed this blog entry https://lkrnac.net/blog/2016/10/aggregate-test-coverage-report/. After we ran the build `./gradlew clean test` and got our reports, one of our team members noted that the whitelists weren't being created properly anymore when we ran `./gradlew clean deployNodes`.

I've gone back to the base Kotlin CorDapp template found here https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin to rule out if it's something we've done wrong with our project structure/gradle. Without JaCoCo added, I see all the whitelist entries I would expect. Once I add the JaCoCo code, I only see the 5 default Corda whitelist entries, and none of my added contract entries.

I'm using JaCoCo version `0.8.1` and coveralls version `2.6.3`. The changes I've made are all within the build.gradle file for the root directory `cordapp-template-kotlin`:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    group = 'net.lkrnac.blog'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    dependencies {
        testCompile("junit:junit:4.12")
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = jacoco_version
    }

    //command for generating subproject coverage reports
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
        }
    }
}

def publishedProjects = subprojects.findAll()
task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport, group: 'Coverage reports') {
    description = 'Generates an aggregate report from all subprojects'

    dependsOn(publishedProjects.test)

    additionalSourceDirs = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
    classDirectories = files(publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.output)
    executionData = files(publishedProjects.jacocoTestReport.executionData)

    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll { it.exists() })
    }

    reports {
        html.enabled = true // human readable
        xml.enabled = true // required by coveralls
    }
}

coveralls {
    sourceDirs = publishedProjects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs.flatten()
    jacocoReportPath = "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacocoRootReport/jacocoRootReport.xml"
}

tasks.coveralls {
    dependsOn jacocoRootReport
}
```

I believe that the problem is coming from simply adding a task where JacocoReport as a parameter. Any thoughts how I could proceed to have both code coverage, along with building my whitelists correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find how to fix the coverage/whitelisting issue. I started stripping away what seemed to be unnecessary code within the subprojects spec, and found that removing everything except the `apply plugin:`, `jacoco`, and `jacocoTestReport` commands yielded both the root Jacoco code coverage, along with the necessary whitelisting. I didn't need to change any of the other code above to get the whitelisting to work.

For reference, subprojects now looks like this:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = jacoco_version
    }

    //command for generating subproject coverage reports
    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
        }
    }
}
```